# PHP Require Path

Tags: php, include, directory, require

I have a directory layout something like `/public_html/foo/bar.php` that I want required in my file with my file require statement being currently `require('../foo/bar.php')` but I'm not getting to it (I keep getting an error saying its not a directory? and failed to open stream).
My file that I'm putting the require in is in `/public_html/foo2/` so I need to go up one directory listing and then find the file to include it but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong right now. Any guesses?

Actual code:

```
require('../objects/user.php/');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Lose the slash after the `php` at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `/` behind your `../objects/user.php` suggesting `user.php` is a directory.
That's why it tells you it is not a directory, because it indeed isn't.

Remove it and you'll probably be fine. (so `../objects/user.php/` becomes `../objects/user.php`)

Comment: Thanks! That was totally it, upvote for the added description of the exact issue!